# Vincular base de datos FireBird a Sql-server

Tags: sql-server, firebird, linkedserver

Necesito añadir una base de datos **Firebird** como servidor vinculado en un **Sql-Server**, pero no soy capaz de hacerlo.
Después de estar un buen rato probando con la versión gratuita del Driver **FireBird** de **IBProvider** y no conseguir nada, he leído que la manera más óptima de hacerlo era mediante **MSDASQL**, llevo un buen rato probando todo lo que he leído y lo que se me ocurre y no soy capaz.
Esto es lo último que he probado y lo que me parece más próximo a conseguirlo, pero algo se me escapa:

```
EXEC sp_addlinkedserver

  @server = 'SRVFB'

  ,@srvproduct = 'base'

  ,@provider = 'MSDASQL'

  ,@provstr = 'Driver=Firebird/InterBase(r) driver;Dbname=SRVFB:C:\FBDB\BASE.FDB;UID=SYSDBA;PWD=masterkey;CHARSET=NONE;Client=C:\firebird\GDS32.dll;'


 EXEC sp_addlinkedsrvlogin

  @rmtsrvname='SRVFB'

  ,@useself='False'

  ,@locallogin=NULL

  ,@rmtuser='SYSDBA'

  ,@rmtpassword='masterkey'
```

@server es la máquina remota (en la misma LAN) donde está alojada la base de datos
@srvproduct es el nombre de la base de datos

Los errores que me da al testear la conexión son:

> El proveedor OLE DB 'MSDASQL' del servidor vinculado 'SRVFB' informó
> de un error. Error de autenticación. No se puede inicializar el objeto
> de origen de datos del proveedor OLE DB 'MSDASQL' para el servidor
> vinculado 'SRVFB'. El proveedor OLE DB 'MSDASQL' del servidor
> vinculado 'SRVFB' devolvió el mensaje '[ODBC Firebird Driver]Your
> user name and password are not defined. Ask your database
> administrator to set up a Firebird login.'. (Microsoft SQL Server,
> Error: 7399)

Os agradecería que me pudierais echar una mano, muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Después de darle tantas vueltas, estaba todo bien...
Solo necesitaba añadir un usuario y concederle permisos en el servidor FireBird,
por lo que parece no acepta conexiones remotas con el usuario 'SYSDBA'.
Espero que le sirva a alguien tan torpe como yo.
Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

me gustaria saber si me puedes ayudar ya que soy nuevo en esto y quiero conectar una BD de Firebird usando SQL Server Management Studio, me recomendaron hacer la instalacion del SSMS dentro del mismo servidor donde esta la BD de Firebird, espero que me puedas ayudar.

Saludos